# Error: Could not start the command: [...] bibtex.exe

Tags: miktex2.9

I created a bibliography file named `bibliografia.bib`. This is the code:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@Book{Russell2000,
  title     = {Θεωρία των Τύπων},
  publisher = {Στάχυ},
  year      = {2000},
  author    = {\textlatin{Bertrand Russell}},
}
```

And this is the main text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{ΜΑΘΗΜΑΤΙΚΑ}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

Ράσελ\cite{Russell2000}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία} %line1
\nocite{*} %line2
\bibliographystyle{plain} %line3
\bibliography{bibliografia} %line4

\end{document}
```

Without the lines `line1`-`line4` everything is OK, but with them compiling doesn't stop. I get this error message:

> ```
> Error: Could not start the command: "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/bibtex.exe" "MainText"
> ```

What maybe wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this code gives you the error? I can compile it fine, I just get a warning telling me that no ``\author`` is given.

Comment: It looks like the issue is connected to a faulty installation of one or more components of MikTeX2.9.

Comment: @Vincent , yes I 'm sure. I tried it many times without any good result.

Comment: @Mico , so what is the solution? I hope that I don't have to reinstall MikTeX...

Comment: How recently did you either install or update MikTeX?

Comment: @Mico, I update it approximately once per month. Also I just now update it. Everything ok whit the update.