# Error: Could not start the command: bibtex.exe

Tags: bibtex, miktex, natbib, texstudio

Recently, I started working with natbib again and now it seems not to be working anymore.

Things that I've discovered:

- usually TexStudio made its own .bbl file, while currently it doesn't
- the following error occurs: *Error: Could not start the command: bibtex.exe "MAINTEX"* where MAINTEX is my file name
- I tried changing my Build & View into txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex
- I'm aware that the post [Error: Could not start the command: [...] bibtex.exe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519731/error-could-not-start-the-command-bibtex-exe) is very similar, perhaps identical

For your information, my MAINTEX file is e.g as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[sort]{natbib}
     
\begin{document}
hi\cite{Lee97}  

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography} 
\bibliography{bib.bib}
 
\end{document}
```

and my bib file is like

```
%Scriptie 2020-2021  

@book{Lee97,
    title={Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature},
    author={Lee, J.M.},
    isbn={9780387983226},
    lccn={97014537},
    series={Graduate Texts in Mathematics},
    url={https://books.google.nl/books?id=N8j9Gf1bQOoC},
    year={1997},
    publisher={Springer New York}
}
```

In addition, I've updated MiKTeX, and in the other post an answer given was refering to a faulty installation. Any idea what might be wrong here?

Comment: I assume you have updated miktex in both miktex user mode and in miktex admin mode. Next thing: have you tried manually running bibtex from the command line? Just to rule out texstudio. Additionally, it's `\bibliography{bib} ` not extension, and I'm not sure alpha is compatible with natbib. Might be better to use plainnat until everything is working

Comment: The problem has been solved by reinstalling TeXStudio. I did not know how to run bibtex manually, whence I tried reinstalling TeXStudio which subsequently did the job!
A question out of interest, when you're saying ''to run bibtex manually'', what do you need to do precisely?

Comment: Start the start the dos prompt or what ever it is called nowadays and type bibtex and hit enter. Just to see if it reacts

Comment: Thanks. If you'd like, you can make your first comment an answer which I then can accept.

Comment: I did not solve it, you did that your self. I'm not sure if you can self answer when you have low number of points

Comment: Ruling out TeXStudio was the inspiration I needed.
Anyhow, I indeed cannot do this because I do not have enough reputation in the TeX-LaTeX account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question: the problem has been solved by simply reinstalling TeXStudio. An easy solution for a vague problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's also happen when a new version of biber is installed, so going to configuration and give the TexStudio or TexMaker the new path (like this "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/biber/bin/windows-x64/biber.exe" %) of biber.exe is also a solution.